# Traversing backward from iframe inside a model a window

Tags: javascript, traversal

i have a modal popup built with jquery UI ($.dialog) that contains an iframe (id='myIframe') with a login form.
the login func calls via Ajax and give access to the user, then it should redirect the user to a different page...but instead it load the page inside the iframe...

i always forget how to solve this issue...

```
parent.location.href= mypage.html **???**
```

can you teach me?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
parent.location.href = "somepage.htm";
```